# Should I use nsmutablearray copy or just assign the pointer when used with blocks

Tags: nsmutablearray, automatic-ref-counting

My project uses ARC and lets say I'm loading a list of persons from a core data database. I have a block that returns this as an NSMutableArray.

```
[DBMgr loadAllContactsFromDB:^(NSMutableArray *array)
                       {
                         self.contactsList = array;
                       }
                 onFailed:(NSError* error)
                       {
                         NSLog(%@, [error localizedDescription]);
                       }
```

I have defined contactsList as

```
@property (strong) NSMutableArray contactsList;
```

Question: I'm assuming `self.contactslist = array` will retain the contents of array as long as it needs, correct?

So something like `self.contactsList = [array mutableCopy]` is redundant, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's declared `strong`, then yes, the array will be retained. Period.